# determine padding for inner ranges on a number line

Tags: algorithm

I have a range, which is .1 to .75.  Within that range is a subrange of .13 to .74.

Within the range, the subrange takes up ~93.8% of the space.

The left side 'padding' of the subrange within the range takes up ~4.6% and the right side 'padding' ~1.5%.

I need to ensure there is at least 5% 'padding' on both sides of the subrange by *expanding the range* (not reducing the size of the inner range).  How to go about quickly determining what the enlarged extents of the range should be?

What if the inner range was [.5, .74] so that only the right side of the outer range needs to be enlarged to achieve minimum 5% padding of the inner range?

not homework :-)

Comment: the outer range should expand so that there is at least 5% of the outer range's length padding both sides of the inner range.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple logic (edited after question correction):

```
 Given:  RangeLeft, RangeRight, SubLeft, SubRight
 MinPadding = (SubRight - SubLeft) * 5 / 90
 NewLeft = Min(RangeLeft, SubLeft - MinPadding)
 NewRight = Max(RangeRight, SubRight + MinPadding)]
```

Comment: Thanks, but subLeft and subRight cannot be changed.  Need to expand the outer range instead.

Comment: It was not stated clearly (yes, I saw some inconsistency in the question)

Comment: sorry for unclear op. https://codepen.io/jedierikb/pen/vrMEEV works when both or neither inner values are close to the outer values, but fails when one of the inner ranges is close and the other is not (for example, if sr = 0.54).  suggestions?

Comment: This approach gives at least 5% **of subrange** on both sides